# Laravel 4 - save tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 tables:

- `posts` => `id`, `title`, `body`, ...
- `tags` => `id`, `name`, `count`
- `post_tag` => `post_id`, `tag_id`

`Post` model has

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

`Tag` model has

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
}
```

Selecting is working, but I want insert to DB

- If new tag - insert to `tags`
- Insert relation to `post_tag`
- Increase tag `count`

For now I have

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = Input::post('title');
$post->body = Input::post('body');

$post->save();
```

I have tags separated with `,`. For example `javascript, jquery, ajax`.

How to do it? Explode tags and then check every tag if exist and then do 2 inserts (to `tags` and `post_tag`) or is there "magic" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this, it'll probably help you

[Inserting related models](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

I think the function you need is `attach`. I've never used but I believe it's what you need. Have a look ;)